# Why my observable variable can not update the "main.dart" in Flutter using GetX?

Tags: flutter, token, flutter-getx, obs

The following code is my `auth_controller.dart` code. I see the `response` comes from the backend works and it is what was expected and I have `token` and the `isAuth` value changes to `true` after I submit the form:

```
enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

class AuthController extends GetxController
    with GetSingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();
  Rx<dynamic>? authMode = AuthMode.Login.obs;
  RxBool? isLoading = false.obs;
  String? _token;
  DateTime? _expiryDate;
  String? _userId;
  Timer? _authTimer;
  final _isAuth = false.obs;

  AnimationController? controller;
  Animation<Offset>? slideAnimation;
  Animation<double>? opacityAnimation;
  // late TextEditingController passwordController;
  // final key = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        milliseconds: 300,
      ),
    );
    slideAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: const Offset(0, -1.5),
      end: const Offset(0, 0),
    ).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller as Animation<double>,
        curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      ),
    );
    opacityAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: controller as Animation<double>,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      ),
    );
    // _heightAnimation.addListener(() => setState(() {}));

    // passwordController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
    // passwordController.dispose();
  }

  bool get isAuth {
    _isAuth.value = token != null;
    return _isAuth.value;
  }

  String? get token {
    if (_expiryDate != null &&
        _expiryDate!.isAfter(DateTime.now()) &&
        _token != null) {
      return _token;
    }
    return null;
  }

  String? get userId {
    return _userId;
  }

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    // print('app is here!!!5555');

    final host = UniversalPlatform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : '127.0.0.1';
    final url = Uri.parse('http://$host:8000/api/$urlSegment');
    //final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/$urlSegment');
    //final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/$urlSegment');

    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,

            //'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      print('this is responsde ');
      print(json.decode(response.body));

      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);

      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      } else {
        _token = responseData['idToken'];
        _userId = responseData['id'];
        _expiryDate = DateTime.now().add(
          Duration(
            seconds: responseData['expiresIn'],
          ),
        );
      }
      _autoLogout();
      // update();
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final userData = json.encode(
        {
          'token': _token,
          'userId': _userId,
          'expiryDate': _expiryDate!.toIso8601String(),
        },
      );
      prefs.setString('userData', userData);

      // print(prefs.getString('userData'));

    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signup(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signup');
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'login');
  }

  Future<bool> tryAutoLogin() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!prefs.containsKey('userData')) {
      return false;
    }
    final Map<String, Object> extractedUserData = Map<String, Object>.from(
        json.decode(prefs.getString('userData') as String));
    final expiryDate =
        DateTime.parse(extractedUserData['expiryDate'] as String);

    if (expiryDate.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
      return false;
    }
    _token = extractedUserData['token'] as String;
    _userId = extractedUserData['userId'] as String;
    _expiryDate = expiryDate;
    // update();
    _autoLogout();
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    _token = null;
    _userId = null;
    _expiryDate = null;
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer!.cancel();
      _authTimer = null;
    }
    // update();
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // prefs.remove('userData');
    prefs.clear();
  }

  void _autoLogout() {
    if (_authTimer != null) {
      _authTimer!.cancel();
    }
    final timeToExpiry = _expiryDate!.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;
    _authTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: timeToExpiry), logout);
  }
}
```

But it will still sticks to the Authentication page and won't go to the Home page as I defined in my `main.dart` file:

```
void main() {
  Get.put(MenuController());
  Get.put(NavigationController());
  Get.put(AuthController());
  Get.put(AuthCard);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => GetMaterialApp(
          initialRoute: AuthController.instance.isAuth
              ? homeScreenRoute
              : authenticationScreenRoute,
          unknownRoute: GetPage(
              name: '/not-found',
              page: () => PageNotFound(),
              transition: Transition.fadeIn),
          getPages: [
            GetPage(
                name: rootRoute,
                page: () {
                  return SiteLayout();
                }),
            GetPage(
                name: authenticationScreenRoute,
                page: () => const AuthenticationScreen()),
            GetPage(name: homeScreenRoute, page: () => const HomeScreen()),
          ],
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'BasicCode',
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: light,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.mulishTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
                .apply(bodyColor: Colors.black),
            pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
              TargetPlatform.iOS: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
              TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            }),
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

What is the problem and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Initial route is set only once when the app starts, and based on what you've shown `isAuth` will always return false by the time `GetMaterialApp` is built.

Wrapping your whole app in an `Obx` is not going to trigger a navigation based on what you have set for the initial route. Its way past that by the time you've run any login attempt.

You need to manually navigate to home screen after a successful login.

Instead I suggest checking for a non null token from storage before the app starts and if its null, go to your auth page and if not, go to your home page. Neither of which would require an `Obx` around `GetMaterialApp` because you need to properly initialize `_isAuth` and `await` it before `runApp()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I am a new learner and don't have much experience, may you help me more and give me a sample code or modify my existing code to understand what do exactly I must do?

Answer (score 0):

I could simply resolve the problem by adding following lines to my `main.dart` file:

```
  home: Obx(() => AuthController.instance.isAuth
      ? const HomeScreen()
      : const AuthenticationScreen()),
```

And removing the followings:

```
   initialRoute
   : AuthController.instance.isAuth
       ? homeScreenRoute
       : authenticationScreenRoute,
```

I also deleted the `Obx` before the `GetMaterialApp()`.

The new `main.dart` looks like this:

```
void main() {
  Get.put(MenuController());
  Get.put(NavigationController());
  Get.put(AuthController());
  Get.put(AuthCard);
  AuthController.instance.isAuth ? runApp(MyApp()) : runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      unknownRoute: GetPage(
          name: '/not-found',
          page: () => PageNotFound(),
          transition: Transition.fadeIn),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(
            name: rootRoute,
            page: () {
              return SiteLayout();
            }),
        GetPage(
            name: authenticationScreenRoute,
            page: () => const AuthenticationScreen()),
        GetPage(name: homeScreenRoute, page: () => const HomeScreen()),
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'BasicCode',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: light,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.mulishTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)
            .apply(bodyColor: Colors.black),
        pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
          TargetPlatform.iOS: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          TargetPlatform.android: FadeUpwardsPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        }),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Obx(() => AuthController.instance.isAuth
          ? const HomeScreen()
          : const AuthenticationScreen()),
    );
  }
}
```